# Log4net Custom ADO Appender (no config): Data is not going into database

Tags: c#, oracle, log4net, log4net-appender

Using log4net (C#) and Oracle, I'm trying to create a custom ADO Appender so that I don't need to use a config file. My code so far

```
public static void CreateAppender()
{
    var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
    hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

    var ADOAppender = new AdoNetAppender();
   AddDateTimeParameterToAppender(ADOAppender, ":log_date", "log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout");
   AddStringParameterToAppender(ADOAppender, ":thread", 255, "%thread");
   AddStringParameterToAppender(ADOAppender, ":log_level", 50, "%level");
   AddStringParameterToAppender(ADOAppender, ":logger", 255, "%logger");
   AddStringParameterToAppender(ADOAppender, ":message", 30000, "%message");

   ADOAppender.ConnectionType =
            "System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

   ADOAppender.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO Log (Datetime,Thread,Log_Level,Logger,Message) VALUES (:log_date, :thread, :log_level, :logger, :message)";

   ADOAppender.ConnectionString = "data source=[db];User ID=[id];Password=[pass]";

   ADOAppender.BufferSize = 1;

  ADOAppender.ActivateOptions();

  log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(ADOAppender);
}

public static void AddDateTimeParameterToAppender(AdoNetAppender appender, string paramName, string conversionPattern)
{
       var param = new AdoNetAppenderParameter { ParameterName = paramName, DbType = System.Data.DbType.DateTime, Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout(conversionPattern)) };
   appender.AddParameter(param);
}

public static void AddStringParameterToAppender(AdoNetAppender appender, string paramName, int size, string conversionPattern)
{
   var param = new AdoNetAppenderParameter
   {
      ParameterName = paramName,
      DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
      Size = size,          
      Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout(conversionPattern))
   };
appender.AddParameter(param);

}
```

I'm not getting any exceptions, yet no data is being inserted into the database. I'm almost positive it has to do with the parameters because when I set all of the values to null, it works.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've googled A LOT but none of the examples I found used the ADO Appender. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tobyb, Thanks for your response, I figured out what I was doing wrong. When adding the DateTime parameter I set the layout to Layout2RawLayoutAdapter when it needed to be RawTimeStampLayout(). I needed to replace `Layout = new Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new PatternLayout(conversionPattern))` with `Layout = new RawTimeStampLayout()`. My updated AddDateTimeParameterToAppender method looks like this..

```
public static void AddDateTimeParameterToAppender(AdoNetAppender appender, string paramName)
{
    var param = new AdoNetAppenderParameter
    {
        ParameterName = paramName, 
        DbType = System.Data.DbType.DateTime,
        Layout = new RawTimeStampLayout()
    };

    appender.AddParameter(param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar experiences with the ADONetAppender. Have you turned on the internal log4net debugging? I don't recall the specifics for my problem, but after turning on debugging I was able to figure it out.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug

Also, I'm sure you have, but ensure you have the 'XmlConfigurator' line in your project.

Details here: 
[Log4Net not writing to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015192/log4net-not-writing-to-the-database?rq=1)