# How can I add the end user's username to the SQL connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a web application that has users, and it connects to SQL Server using Windows Authentication with a generic service account. Using SQL Profiler, I can see the ApplicationName from the app's connection string, and the service account as the LoginName. Ideally, I'd like to see/filter the end user who made the request.

In the code, when creating the ADO.NET or EF Connection, I can append `User.Identity.Name` onto the Application Name property of the connection string, like "MyApp-JOHNDOE", and that would work. But does that screw anything up? Would it interfere with connection pooling or caching or anything like that, since there would be many different connection strings connecting to the database?

If Application Name isn't the right place, is there another property of the connection that I could use?

Comment: I think that changing the connectionstring will invalidate the pooling. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#pool-creation-and-assignment _When a new connection is opened, if the connection string is not an exact match to an existing pool, a new pool is created._

Comment: @Steve Well crap, that pretty much answers it - I don't want to mess up connection pooling. Any idea how else to accomplish this, aside from maybe adding a comment inside the SQL Query and then seeing it in the TextData?

Comment: There are some logging frameworks that can write to the a custom database table and can be used, when you entry that particular block of code to write into that log table whatever you like.  Perhaps you could extend this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015192/log4net-not-writing-to-the-database

Comment: As noted, I don't think it is a good idea or even practical to mess with the connection strings to the database. They are quite much APPLICATION wide, should be encrypted, and are something that is best left alone. And messing with the connection strings is going to be in most cases application wide - not per user anyway. In fact, even code you write should not care or see what the connection string is - but only know that you have a connection you can use in code.